# Selecting and joining rows from multiple tables based on MAX(Column Name)

Tags: sql, firebird, greatest-n-per-group

Overall, my goal is to obtain a customer's email, code, and most recent rewards balance from three tables.

The three tables are: Customer, CustomerCode, and Rewards

The tables look roughly like the following...

### Customer

```
id   email           lastcode
----|---------------|-----------
000 |test@test.com  | 1234test
001 |test1@test.com | 5678test
002 |test2@test.com | test1234
003 |test3@test.com | test5678
```

### CustomerCode

```
id   code      customer
----|---------|---------
100 |1234test | 000
101 |5678test | 001
102 |test1234 | 002
103 |test5678 | 003
```

### Rewards

```
customercode  logdate      balance
-------------|------------|--------
100          | 01/01/2016 | 1200
101          | 04/05/2016 | 40
102          | 06/22/2016 | 130
102          | 10/14/2016 | 220
103          | 12/03/2016 | 500
103          | 01/18/2017 | 750
```

I'm trying to gather information from all the tables linking back to the customer. I'm currently using the following SQL query but am running into some issues.

```
SELECT Customer.email, Customer.lastcode, CustomerCode.id, Rewards.balance, MAX(Rewards.logdate)
FROM Customer
JOIN CustomerCode ON Customer.lastcode=CustomerCode.code
JOIN Rewards ON CustomerCode.id=Rewards.CustomerCode
GROUP BY Customer.Email, Customer.LastCode, CustomerCode.id, Rewards.Balance
```

### Results

As you can see, I'm getting multiple results for the same customer, but I only want to get the most recent rewards balance for each customer.

```
email           lastcode    id    balance    logdate
---------------|-----------|-----|----------|-----------
test@test.com  | 1234test  | 100 | 1200     | 01/01/2016
test1@test.com | 5678test  | 101 | 40       | 04/05/2016
test2@test.com | test1234  | 102 | 130      | 06/22/2016
test2@test.com | test1234  | 102 | 220      | 10/14/2016
test3@test.com | test5678  | 103 | 500      | 12/03/2016
test3@test.com | test5678  | 103 | 750      | 01/18/2017
```

Is there any way I can eliminate those duplicate records and only display the most recent rewards balance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery or aggregation for this:

```
SELECT c.email, c.lastcode, cc.id, r.balance, r.logdate
FROM Customer c JOIN
     CustomerCode cc
     ON c.lastcode = cc.code JOIN
     Rewards r
     ON cc.id = r.CustomerCode JOIN
     (SELECT r.CustomerCode, MAX(r.logdate) as max_logdate
      FROM Rewards r
      GROUP BY r.CustomerCode
     ) rr
     ON rr.CustomerCode = r.CustomerCode AND rr.max_logdate = r.logdate;
```

Comment: This is a step in the right direction. I'm doing some additional testing now. Thank you so much for your quick response!

Comment: Can confirm that this did it for me! Thanks again Gordon.

Comment: @NickRoberts Does my answer below do it?

Comment: Yes Skafinski, your answer works as well. Double checking query times, it seems like that is the better option for my situation so I will revise the accepted answer.
Skafinski Query Time: 54 sec
Gordon Query Time: 1 min 32 sec

Comment: @NickRoberts . . . You can see my comment on skafinski's answer.  I don't think it does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

sth like this?

```
SELECT
  costumer.email,
  costumer.lastcode,
  reward.costumercode,
  reward.balance
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
        rewards.costumercode,
        MAX(rewards.balance) as balance
      FROM rewards
      GROUP BY 1) AS reward
JOIN costumercode ON costumercode.id = reward.costumercode
JOIN costumer ON costumer.id = costumercode.costumer
```

It is more optimized than Gordon's anwser, and more clean IMHO.

Comment: This chooses the maximum balance, not the balance on the latest date.  I don't think it chooses "most recent rewards balance", unless the balances are steadily increasing.

Comment: Understandable. Made edits and will rerun queries to double check.